# How can I count queries having IN clause in Hibernate + Spring Boot Setup?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can I count queries having IN clause in Hibernate + Spring Boot Setup?

I want to count all queries (emit a metric) having an IN clause along with the number of params in the IN clause.

One way I found is to use StatementInspector. But that will be costly as I will have to find *IN* in the sql query string, requiring pattern matching.

Comment: Expose metrics for queries like execution time etc. publish those to something like Prometheus and use that to query .

Comment: I know that IN queries are the problem, but I want count on the number of params in the IN filter to figure out what's exactly happening

Comment: You nowhere stated that you had a problem but you only wanted logging. If that isn't your actual question then ask the actual question you have.

Comment: I never said logging, I said a metric for the count of queries having IN clause. Please re-read the question.

Comment: I know what you asked which was a metric, which has been answered. If it is for troubleshooting you already have the solution (the statementinspector).